# UPDATE query vs. Table FILTER yields different rows count (MS ACCESS)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem with count of updated rows through UPDATE query.

When I run UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE t002Vyk 
INNER JOIN tZemnyPlyn ON t002Vyk.BMsID = tZemnyPlyn.[ID budovy] 
SET t002Vyk.isZemnyPlynHistoricky = Yes;
```

it says, that **2916** rows will be updated.

[image: qZemnyPlynUpdate rows count]

I run the UPDATE query. (I tried different queries as well, with same results).

When I then filter the table `t002Vyk` ONLY on field `isZemnyPlynHistoricky` = `YES`, I only get **2701** rows.

[image: t002FilteredOnlyOnIsZemnyPlyn]

Just to provide all info, here is the design view of field `isZemnyPlynHistoricky`:
[image: t002VykDesignIsZemnyPlyn]
(I also tried using number data type, with 0/1 values, no luck)

**My questions**
*Why do I get different results in filtered table, than in UPDATE query? How to solve the problem?*

Comment: Just a thought: When you join a first table to a second table, you can end up with a result set _larger_ than the first table.  Maybe this explains your observations, and, if so, therr may not be anything to worry about.

Comment: Tim, Your comment got me on track. It had to do with duplicate ID's in the `tZemnyPlyn` table. It "UPDATED" them more than once. Hence the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
In the `tZemnyPlyn` table, there were duplicate ID's `[ID budovy]`, which were counted more than once time in UPDATE query results.
After creating a unique list of `[ID budovy]` the UPDATE query showed 2701 rows as well as the table did.

Thanks to Tim Biegeleisen's comment, for getting me on track.